# How can I require a library newer than the one required by the Play! Framework?

Tags: playframework

I need a newer version than 1.5 of the oval framework, so I try to add it to the dependencies but play requires 1.5 which overrides my dependency.  How do I force play to let me use a newer version?  (I know technically I could change it in $PLAY_HOME$/framework/dependencies.yml, but that seems like a bad idea)

My conf/dependencies.yml

```
require:
    - play
    - net.sf.oval -> oval 1.7
```

My error

```
~ Some dependencies have been evicted,
~
~   oval 1.7 is overriden by oval 1.50
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to use `force` option:

```
    - net.sf.oval -> oval 1.7:
            force: true
```

Comment: To all readers as me who won't note at the first time : there is a mandatory ':' at the end of the lib name-version ! Thus said, BrownFurSeal got the point, thanks for the tip.